# Am I obtaining the Incorrect Equation for this Joint Probability density Function?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am confused over how I am messing the equation up to solve this problem listed below

[image: Given this Problem here]

**I was asked in Part C to find P(X > Y).**

Therefore I made a double integral as such:

[image: My Equation]

The answer to the problem is 15/16, but why I am I getting -1 by doing it this way?

Am I calculating the equation incorrectly?

Comment: but for $y > 1$ the integral $\int_y^1 f$ becomes negative for positive $f$…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integration domain is just wrong, you don't consider the restriction $X < 1$, e.g. $y = \frac{3}{2}$ is part of your domain and for this the inner integral becomes negative. 
Nevertheless $y = \frac{3}{2}$ is not valid for the domain $\{X > Y\}$

So your double integral should look like $$\int_0^1 \int_y^1 \ldots$$ because $X>Y$ implies $y < 1$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but are you saying that I should use the range of X for the outer bound integral? This is because since 2 is not in the range of X, I should use the range 0< x< 1

Comment: No… I'm saying that you have to restrict the range of Y to the given restriction $$\{X > Y\}$$ And this domain can be written as $$0 < y < 1, y < x < 1$$ what then gets your integration domain.

Comment: I see. I believe I understand now. Thank you so much!